# Kadane Algorithm variation with append and removeFirst operations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Kadane algorithm does a great job finding the max sum contiguous subarray in O(n) time and O(1) space. I have a use case where I frequently need to alter the array by removing the first item while appending a new item in a single operation then re-calculate the max sub-array sum.

An obvious approach would be to reprocess the entire array after every operation in O(n) time, is there a more efficient way?

The sliding window technique seems to work for fixed size sub-arrays, but that is not my case. I need the maximum sum sub-array regardless its size.